# How to apply active class to bootstrap Tab ui

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've a bootstrap ui tab angularjs directive that sets the first tab as an  active tab by default. Problem here is, if you are in tabs, other than the first tab, and try refreshing the page, since the default active class is on first tab, on refresh it shows first tab as active. However the content shown will be from the correct tab.
Bootstrap directive:

```
var configDirectives = angular.module('configDirectives', []);

configDirectives.directive('configTabs', function(){
  return{
  restrict:'A',
  template: '\
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">\
    <li class="active"><a href="#categories" data-    toggle="tab">categories</a></li>\
<li><a href="#uploadassets" data-toggle="tab">upload assets</a></li>\
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">lorem ipsum</a></li>\
  </ul>'
}});
```

My question is : can we set this active class dynamically rather than hard-coding it in first li element?

Comment: I bet this isn't the proper way to handle it, but I for myself have had the same problem a while ago. I solved this by using the location. So depending on which location you are on (the # part in your URL), the according tab would be set to active. As I said: I'm pretty sure it's not the proper way of doing so, but it actually is one and it works (maybe also for you).

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class with custom variable:

```
ng-class="{'active' : selectedType == 'categories'}"
```

And ng-click to select active tab (inside your a href or div or whatever):

```
ng-click="selectedTab = 'categories'"
```

Add 'selectedType' to the directive scope

scope: {
      selectedType: '='
   }